# Returning values from events in ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, events, event-handling, logic, return

I have been working in an ActionScript 3 card game project lately and I ran into aproblem with Event Handlers which I found kinda complicated. I'll try to explain it:

There is an indeterminate amount of Players taking turns to play their cards. After they do that they relegate the turn to the player on their right.

```
function Round(table:Table, lead:Player)/*Table is the list of players. 
Lead is the person that starts the round*/
{
    private var query:int = 0;
    private var roundEnd:Boolean = false;
    private var currentplater:Player = lead;

    while(roundEnd == false)
    {
        query = currentPlayer.hasTurn();/*I'll explain this one later. It's 
        the problematic one*/

        //Game stuff happens.

        currentPlayer = currentPlayer.nextPlayer;/*Once the turn is over,
        it gets assigned to the next player*/
        if(currentPlayer.nextPlayer == lead)
        {
            roundEnd = true;//Everyone has played
        }
    }
}
```

As commented there, the complicated one is `hasTurn`. That function must activate from the Player class and trigger a permission for the player to handle an event AND return an integer value.

```
public function hasTurn():int
{
    for each(var cards:Card in hand)
    {
        cards.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playCard);
    }
}
```

And after that

```
public function playCard(theCard:Card)
{
    for each(var cards:Card in hand)
    {
        cards.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playCard);
    }

    //More game stuff happens. Not currently relevant.

}
```

What I do here is allowing every card in the player's hand to be played and then taking those permissions away when one of them is, but I'm never returning a value to `Round` and, more importantly, am not able to allow the next player to play later. I have gone around this problem several times in my head, but can't seem to find a way for `hasTurn` to return a value or end its execution so the `Round` code can continue working. Am I handling the logic of this problem the wrong way?

Comment: Note: I'm not sure if the question is clear enough as it is. I did my best effort to convey the nature of such a specific problem, but tell me if I have to edit the post. Thank you

Comment: what you are doing is plain wrong  - you can't use while nor other loops for game execution loop (it is not JAVA) - simply because in flash loops stops executing/rendering everything until it finishes. It might work - the loop - if it was an enter frame loop.

Comment: @Lukasz'Severiaan'Grela Interesting. I'll look into that. What path can I use to solve this problem not involving loops?

Comment: now to the game - in your example theCard doesn't come from anything, loop suggest that it should populate it's value in there, secondly for click events for the card you do not register it on every card as click bubbles and can be cought by single listener. you do not have to regisdter it with each loop unless after clicking you intend to unregister. From the event handler you can't return any value but you could register afor another event which will be dispatched from playCard. hasTurn in your example doesn't do much anyway but it is simple function so it can return value

Comment: @Lukasz'Severiaan'Grela theCard was cards. Already fixed that. Other than that, well... I know that this logic has problems. That's why I'm asking. My main objective was to at least leave pseudocode good enough to make people understand my objectives...

Answer (score 0):

Heres my 2cent on this.

What you should do to properly handle this is. Have a class that manages your players, say TurnManager.
TurnManager is a class that has two array of players. One that is Global player array and another that is used to give out turns and then remove the players from this array. Once this array is empty, meaning that every player had their turn for this round, it should repopulate itself using the global array.

```
public class TurnManager{

    private Array _allPlayers;
    private Array _currentPlayers;

    public void TurnManager(Array players){
        _allPlayers = players;

        foreach(Player player in _allPlayers){
            player.endTurnFunction = this.OnRoundFinished;
        }

        RefillPlayerArray();
        Init();
    }

    public void Init(){
        ActTurn();
    }

    public void ActTurn(){
        if(_currentPlayers.length > 0){
            /*Round isnt finished*/
            Player _currentPlayer = _currentPlayers[0];
            _currentPlayer.PromptForTurnActions();
        } else {
            /*Round is finished*/
            OnRoundFinished();
            RefillPlayerArray();
            /*Restarting round*/
            _currentPlayer.PromptForTurnActions();
        }
    }

    public void RefillPlayerArray(){
        //copy all players from _allPlayer and add them to _currentPlayer
        //make sure to empty _currentPlayer First
    }

    public void OnRoundFinished(){
        //this is called when the round is finished.
    }

    public void PlayerFinishedTurn(Player player){
        ActTurn();
    }
}
```

At the start when the TurnManager creates itself it should loop through all the player to give them the function to call when their turn is over so the TurnManager can continue.

As far as your Card problem goes. The TurnManager handles turns, order and prompt players for actions. You should also have a CardManager that handles the player's card. When a player clicks on a card in its hand it will go to the CardManager and be asked to player. Then the CardManager can ask to your GUI to play animations and what not.

Hope this helps  :)

Comment: You have a variable in TurnManager set as the current player, if a player clicks on a card to play you should check if hes able to play it, by looking at the current player variable in TurnManager, Also this as no recursivity at all.

Comment: you can delete unrelated comments : )

Answer (score 0):

as discussed in comments:

- make enter frame loop for game actions

e.g. when user clicks play for example among other game setup:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameLoop, false, 0, true);

protected function gameLoop(e:Event):void
{
    //here the code for game
}
```

You could register single event for clicikn on cards e.g. by registering on the container of the cards

```
cardsHolder.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playCard, false, 0, true);

protected function playCard(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    if(e.target is Card)
    {
    //we have clicked on a Card not on another object
    var playedCard:Card = e.target as Card;
    //do whatever with playedCard needs to be done - you can set a flag
    //that it was clicked and next turn is allowed for example
    }
}
```

once you done with handling the click event you are ready to change player

I think this is the algorithm you could follow:

1. start game - shuffle deck, choose first player
2. let player interact with cards
3. evaluate it - this depends on the type of card game in general if playermade valid move
4. check finish game - if playerhas actualy won
5. not finished then next player

best regards